# Facebook api authentication PHP

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, interface

In my siteweb I'm implementing authentication with Facebook API.

```
<fb:login-button onlogin="fbLoginEvent(arguments)">Enter with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

My function fbLoginEvent:

```
function fbLoginEvent( args ) {
    //console.log( "fbLogin", args );
    //var session = FB.getSession();
    var session = FB.getAuthResponse();
    if (session) {
        fbCheckSession(session, function(data) {
            if (data.result) {
            fbLoginNow();
    } else {                        
            $('#facebook-register').data("overlay").load();

    }
         });
}
}
```

And my function for check the session:

```
var fbLogin = { status: false, uid: 0, access_token: "" };

function fbCheckSession( session, callback ) {
    if ( session && $.type(callback) == "function" ) {
    ajaxCall( "facebook", "check_session", {uid: session.uid, token: session.access_token}, function(data){
        if ( data.result ) {
        fbLogin.status = true;
        fbLogin.fbuid = session.uid;
        fbLogin.uid = data.info.id;
        fbLogin.access_token = session.access_token;
            callback( { result: true, info: { name: data.info.name, fbLogin: fbLogin } } );
            } else {
        callback( { result: false } );
            }
    });
}                   
}
```

I made ​​various checks and I have noticed that uid and tokens value are empty.
Any solution?
Thk

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake by assigning `session` variable to `FB.getAuthResponse` function of JS-SDK

Use

```
var session = FB.getAuthResponse();
```

Instead of

```
var session = FB.getAuthResponse
```

You also using incorrect properties names, `authResponse` use the same format as [FB.getLoginStatus](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) not in format returned by `getSession` of previous version of JS-SDK.

`uid` named `userID`, and `access_token` is `accessToken`

Comment: session.uid and session.access_token are empty. I don't know.